# how to handle disconnect error for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am seeing this uncaught exception in my Node.js process:

> ```
> Uncaught exception: { Error: read ETIMEDOUT
>     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:162:27)
>   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: { isGetMore: true } }
> ```

I tried capturing/trapping it using:

```
import * as mdb from 'mongodb'
const d = new mdb.MongoClient(...);
d.on('error', () => {...});  // trap it here
```

but that does not seem to be able to trap the error. Anyone know how I can do so?

Comment: have your tried wrapping it in a try-catch instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 distinct types of connection errors when using the MongoDB driver:

1. Errors during initial connection
2. Errors after initial connection is established

The 'error' event is used to handle (2). It looks like you're looking for the correct way to handle initial connection errors. For those, you should either pass a callback to `connect()` or `.catch()` on the promise that `connect()` returns.

```
const NUM_RETRIES = 3;
const delay = 1000;
let error = null;
for (let i = 0; i < NUM_RETRIES; ++i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, i * delay));
  }
  try {
    await mdb.MongoClient.connect(uri);
    break;
  } catch (err) {
    error = err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **monk** for the problem. I had faced the same problem a year ago but the **monk** saved me.

Here is a Example

```
const monk = require('monk')
const db = monk()

db.on('timeout', () => {
  console.log('Mongo connection lost')
})

db.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Mongo connection closed')
})

db.on('reconnect', () => {
  console.log('Mongo reconnected')
})

db._db.on('timeout', () => {
  console.log('Mongo connection lost')
})

db._db.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Mongo connection closed')
})

db._db.on('reconnect', () => {
  console.log('Mongo reconnected')
})
```

Comment: maybe those events are the same names as the event names for mongodb library? (timeout, close, error, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The [client](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/MongoClient.html#db) doesn't emit events. The [DB](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Db.html#event:close) does. Get [access to the db](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/) with `client.db(dbName)`

```
import * as mdb from 'mongodb'
const d = new mdb.MongoClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
  if (err) //do something
  const d = client.db(dbName);
  // available events: close,error,fullsetup,parseError,reconnect,timeout
  d.on('timeout', () => {...});  // trap it here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try it out with d.connect:

```
import * as mdb from 'mongodb'
const d = new mdb.MongoClient(...);
d.connect("your url").then().catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
})
```